# Cumsum w/ panel data: different start dates

Tags: r, cumsum

Trying to find the cumsum across different types of contracts. Each has a unique stop (i.e. delivery) date with several months of expected delivery leading up to that date. Needing to calculate the cumsum of all expected deliveries before the actual delivery date.

For some reason the cumsum/rollsum function is not working. I have tried both DT and dplyr versions but both have failed.

Here is a simplified data for the problem I am working on.

```
df <- data.frame(report_year = c(rep(2017,10), rep(2018,10)), 
       report_month = c(seq(1,5,1), seq(2,6,1), seq(3,7,1), seq(2,6,1)),
       delivery_year = c(rep(2017,10), rep(2018,10)), 
       delivery_month = c(rep(5,5),rep(6,5), rep(7,5), rep(6,5)),
       sum = c(rep(seq(100,500,100), 4)),
       cumsum = c(rep(c(100,300,600,1000,1500),4)))
```

The first 5 columns is what I currently have.

I am trying to get the last column (i.e. cumsum)

I am probably doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, cumsum2 := cumsum(sum), by = .(report_year, delivery_month)][]`

Comment: Thank you @markus. This solution works however only when it is confined to a given year. If the lag straddles multiple years it does not work

Comment: Hey EDennnis, remember to accept and answer so people know your question has been resolved.

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt how do I accept an answer if the one I want to accept is in a comment? I would like to accept markus comment that is why I upvoted it

Comment: Then you cannot, and have to ask that person to post it as an answer.

Comment: @markus, can you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you

Comment: @EDennnis Thanks, but I think you should accept G.Grothendieck's answer which gives desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question did not specifically define which grouping columns to use so this may have to be modified slightly depending on what you want but this does it without any packages:

```
df$cumsum <- NULL  # remove the result from df shown in question
transform(df, cumsum = ave(sum, delivery_year, delivery_month, FUN = cumsum))
```

Note that although the above works you may run into some problems using `sum` and `cumsum` as the column names due to confusion with the functions of the same name so you might want to use Sum and Cumsum, say.  For example if you don't null out cumsum as we did above then FUN = cumsum will think that you want to apply the cumsum column which is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Use **arrange** and **mutate**

```
# Import library
library(dplyr)

# Calculating cumsum
df %>%
  group_by(delivery_year, delivery_month) %>%
  arrange(sum) %>% 
  mutate(cs = cumsum(sum))
```

Output

```
   report_year report_month delivery_year delivery_month   sum cumsum    cs
         <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1        2017            1          2017              5   100    100   100
 2        2017            2          2017              6   100    100   100
 3        2018            3          2018              7   100    100   100
 4        2018            2          2018              6   100    100   100
 5        2017            2          2017              5   200    300   300
 6        2017            3          2017              6   200    300   300
 7        2018            4          2018              7   200    300   300
```